# I can't figure out how to install Firestarter Fedora

Tags: fedora, install, yum, firewall

I am feeling stupid. I have been searching for 3 hours with no success.
I installed Fedora 14 and tried to do `yum install firestarter` but the package was not found. 
I also tried from a GUI and found nothing. 
It is at fedoras repository? 
Maybe I should configure the repository, but all I found are dated. Any help? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Firestarter` hasn't been in the fedora repository since Fedora 11.  It's listed as a deprecated package on their [wiki](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Deprecated_packages).  It's recommended that you use `system-config-firewall` instead.

Do you have a particular reason for wanting to use firestarter?  If you really want to install it you can try grabbing the source from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firestarter/).

Comment: Thank you for the response:) I was looking for a good grafical gui for firewall to use at a demostration. So there arent any good-equilivement GUI for ipatables?

Comment: What have you found to be missing from system-config-firewall (System -> Administration -> Firewall)?